# .zshrc.symlink overwrite config

Tags: macos, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I've installed these https://github.com/holman/dotfiles .dotfiles, every thing works well, but as I see `.zshrc` dosent exist anymore in `~/`.

So the thing is that I want to overwrite some config from the `zshrc.symlink`.

First I do `ls -l .zshrc` and I get `/Users/hiero/.dotfiles/zsh/zshrc.symlink`.

So if I edit the `zshrc.symlink`, I add

```
ZSH_THEME="honukai"
```

to change the theme but even if I restart, settings are not updated, and I see the old theme, if I `$ZSH_THEME - command not found honukai`.

I'm doing something wrong?
Can someone please explain how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> So if I edit the zshrc.symlink, I add
>
> ```
> ZSH_THEME="honukai"
> ```

You would need to do more than that. You will need to source your oh-my-zsh configuration, for example as the last statement in `zshrc.symlink`.

One way or another, if the oh-my-zsh configuration is not included, the theme will not be applied.

> if I
>
> ```
> $ZSH_THEME - command not found honukai.
> ```

Not very clear what you're trying to do there. It looks as if you're trying to run `$ZSH_THEME`, whose value is `honukai`, and there is no such command, "honukai".